# How to control where an edge to and from the same node contacts the node in visNetwork or vis.js?

Tags: r, vis.js, visnetwork

In the R package `visNetwork`, if an edge connects a node to itself, is it possible to control where the edge contacts the node?

```r
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:2)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1),
                    to = c(1, 2),
                    arrows = c("to,from", "to"))
visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

[image: Imgur]

I tried different settings and it seems that the orientation of the same-node edge is always as displayed above. It may be able to edit the points of contact manually but it would be better to be able to set the contact points using an R script.